# Forcing WP to embedd a video when using a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, youtube

With the following shortcode for YouTube videos, how can I make it such that WordPress still automatically embeds the video for me?

```
<?  /** YouTube shortcode, usage: [youtube align="alignleft" id="123456789" ] */
    function shortcode_youtube($atts) {  
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
            "id"    => '', 
            "align" => 'aligncenter'  
        ), $atts));  
        return '<div class="'.$align.'">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id.'</div>';  
    }  
    add_shortcode("youtube", "shortcode_youtube");      
?>
```

What it currently does, is display the url of the video. What I want is it to embed the video (like it would do if I just pasted the video's url into the wp editor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more graceful way to do this, but it works:

```
function shortcode_youtube($atts) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "id"    => '', 
        "align" => 'aligncenter'  
    ), $atts));

    global $wp_embed;
    $content = '[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $id . '[/embed]';
    $embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $content );

    return '<div class="'.$align.'">' . $embed . '</div>';  
}  
add_shortcode("youtube", "shortcode_youtube");
```